# Angular cli Multi Component in single .ts file

Tags: angular, angular-directive, angular-cli

I am new to Angular cli framework and angular2, i want add 2 `@Components` in single .ts file how can I proceed?

I tried but getting error.

Comment: Could you provide some more information about what you've tried and be more specific about what exactly you're trying to do?  It's hard to answer without more specific information.

Comment: I want to create accordion as in below link using angular CLI https://embed.plnkr.co/NzMrJixtwZv0l2ohiZgQ/ so please help me out

Answer (score 1):

The CLI does not facilitate this as it goes against the single responsibility suggestion defined in the style guide. ([reference](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/style-guide.html#!#single-responsibility))